# What do the two parentheses do?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Can someone explain to me what the two parentheses do in this code below just before calling the `ToTable` function?

```
Dim modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder
modelBuilder.Entity(Of IdentityUser)().ToTable("AspNetUsers")
```

[MSDN Library - DbModelBuilder.Entity(Of TEntityType) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Entity%60%601%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true)

Comment: `(Of Identity)` is the generic type parameter, `()` because it is a function (although not obligatory in VB.NET, I prefer to write it, to distinguish between properties and methods).

Comment: In C# this would be `modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()`, which makes it a bit clearer I think.

Comment: OK, good to know that the parentheses is just there because it's a function and that they aren't mandatory to include in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double parenthesis are simply used to call a parameterless function.  The segment `modelBuilder.Entity(Of IdentityUser)` resolves to a function, and the `()` following it calls it without any parameters or arguments.

The `.ToTable` following it is acting on the return value of that function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This was a quite simple question but sometimes even the most obvious things need to be sorted out in order to be sure of what the code actually means.